# Subtract days from date

Tags: php

How do I take away days from a date? So for example the the second line is the line which doesn't work, just wondering how I would take away days from a date?

```
 $statement_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date[$selected_int])); 
 $statement_view = $statement_date (-14 days);
```

Comment: Do you mean **$statement_date (-14 days);** (note the missing "t")?

Comment: @TomChadaravicius thanks for noticing the typo xD Still doesn't work though ahha but I didnt expect it to

Comment: Thank you, I am looking at the code now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `date` to substract or add days (hours, minutes etc.), because, as per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `date`:

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format

And, well, you can't do what you want to a string.

To achieve what you want going the object oriented style, you have to create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object first:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // this will return today OR
$date = new DateTime('2010-05-20'); // this will return the needed date
```

Next, you may use `sub` to [subtract](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) or `add` to [add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) a date interval:

```
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

This will output `2016-02-04`

**Update**

You requested your code example:

```
$date = new DateTime('01/28/2016');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P14D'));
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

this will output

```
01/14/2016
```

Of course, don't forget to substitute `01/28/2016` for `$statement_date`

Comment: thanks for the answer I can see how this would be executed however is there a way you can apply it to the example and i'll be sure to mark this the answer I just don't see how I'm able to use this in my example; `$statement_date` echos out the date like this `01/28/2016` m,d,Y

Comment: Your requested code will look as `$date = new DateTime($date[$selected_int]);`, or some other variable to pass to **DateTime** constructor; otherwise the date will never change

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add/subtract. The below will subtract 14 days (3600*24*14):

```
$unixRefDate=strtotime($date[$selected_int]);
$unixDate=($unixRefDate-(3600*24*14));
$statement_view=date('Y-m-d', $unixDate);
```

Care should be taken of the timezone.